# Google Drive API: list all files at once

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

Currently, I'm using `Files: list` API below to get all the files
`https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list`

Attached screenshot contains the parameters used where I've provided (pagesize=1000). This only returns 1000 files per call. I have to set (pageToken='nextPageToken' value from previous response)

Is there a way to for the API to return all the files instead of having to set (pageToken='nextPageToken' value from previous response) ?. Please advise
[image]

Comment: If the number of your files and folders is more than 1000 and when you want to retrieve the list of all files and folders, `pageToken` is required to be used. For example, if the number of folders are less than 1000 and when you want to retrieve the folder list, you can retrieve it without using `pageToken` by the search query. Or, how about using Drive Service of Google Apps Script? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive) But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So I'm not sure whether this is the suitable for your situation. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: No there is no way to List more then 1000 files without pagination.

Addional information.

If you check the documentation that you yourself have [linked](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

[image]

You will notice that it states that the default page size is 100, that means that if you don't send the page size parameter that it will automatically be set to 100 by the system.

You will also notice that it states `Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive.` this means that you can max set pagesize to 1000

If you want additional files you need to use the nextpagetoken to get another set of rows.

There is no other way around pagination if you want more then the 1000 rows.  I dont know what your doing but maybe using the  the Q parameter to search for just the files you are looking for and thereby limiting the response to under 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that my testing suggests that you get 100 back for My Drives and 460 (?) for Shared Drives. I have never got 1000 back for either type. You will need to iterate each "page" in turn

Comment: For anyone getting fewer results than pageSize (e.g. 460 or even 100 when pageSize=1000), the fields you specify can affect how many items are returned. For example, including fields like "parents" or "permissions" will usually limit the page size to 460, and some other metadata fields will limit it to 100. If you only specify basic fields (id, name) or exclude the fields parameter entirely (giving you a default set of fields), you can usually get up to 1000 records back if pageSize=1000.